# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'currentUser.email')

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, typeerror

I'm using react-native with the expo and creating user profile with redux came to the error mentioned in Profile.js while using currentUser for present user details.

[image: Profile.js]

when reloading the app without current user details I got undefined

[image: without currentUser]

Comment: can you once try like this {currentUser?.name} and {currentUser?.email}

Comment: If you want to persist redux state (so even if you refresh page, currentUser will have the very last value) you should use [redx-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). [This](https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-use-redux-persist-in-react-native-with-asyncstorage) is a useful how to.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `currentUser` is undefined and you can't access the property of undefined. In order to access the property of object you first need to make sure that the variable has an object.
You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
Try this:

```
<Text>{currentUser?.name}</Text>
<Text>{currentUser?.email}</Text>
```